# Visual Studio show me this error v142 tools

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Today I'm trying to build a source sent by my friend but visual studio (version 2017) show me an error.

I already have tried to install and re-target the windows sdk version without success

- SDK 10.0.18362
- 10.0.17763
- 10.0.17738

The error is this:

> Error MSB8020 The build tools for v142 (Platform Toolset = 'v142') cannot be found. To build using the v142 build tools, please install v142 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".   phlib   D:\Visual Studio\IDE\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets    67

I don't know why it doesn't work and I have installed all libraries.

Comment: Thanks man! I have fix it, i just downloaded the VS2019 and reinstalled the SDK version 10.0.17 (the last one before the version 18...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install (v142) Build tools in Visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901371/how-to-install-v142-build-tools-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved from a comment into an answer:

> This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56901371/8746648). It seems the project was created on
>    a newer version of Visual Studio, that is 2019. You tagged the question with
>    [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017), I suspect that is the problem.
>
> *- asynts Aug 24 at 12:01*