# Visual Studio 2019 is not showing Device target option for UWP

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, hololens

I am following the Unity development tutorial for Hololens 2.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/unity-development-overview?tabs=mrtk%2Carr%2Chl2

The Unity build generates visual studio files without issues.

When opening with Visual Studio 2019, I do **not** see a `Device` target option under targets drop down.

However when I open in Visual Studio 2017, I do see the `Device` target option.

The visual studio 2019 menu looks completely different from what is in tutorials:

Please see screenshot below:
[image]

Visual Studio 2017 is not supposed to work with hololens 2, and when I try to build in VS2017, it gives an error:
`MSB8020    The build tools for v142 (Platform Toolset = 'v142') cannot be found.` 
I tried changing the build tools to 141 and 140 under project properties, but it strangely still gives the same error.
The tutorial states minimum version required is Visual Studio 2019, so it is not supposed to work with an older version.

This is what Visual Studio 2019 is supposed to look like according to tutorial above
[image]

I made sure device is connected and is in developer mode. This seems to be something missing in VS2019

Below are all the components I have installed based on the tutorial.

Can anyone help figure out why the `Device` or `Remove Machine` options are not showing up under Visual Studio 2019?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install (v142) Build tools in Visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901371/how-to-install-v142-build-tools-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 5):

I has the same problem, my solution was install all C++ development libraries

and set the UWP project on Visual studio to "Set As Startup Project".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is becasue the wrong project got set as Default Startup Project, must be changed by right clicking on the correct project and selecting `Set as Default Startup Project`

Answer (score 0):

Just checked what is installed on my machine.
At the UWP development tab the option C++ (v142) Universal Windows Platform tools is checked. Try if that fixes it.

Are you working on the latest Version of Visual Studio?

Could you check if you can deploy to the HoloLens Emulator?

Are you working with Unity/Unreal or just testing with an example downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

to see TARGET -> DEVICE
This is becasue the wrong project got set as Default Startup Project,
must be changed by right clicking on the correct project and selecting
.... Set as Default Startup Project
......OK !!!